# PS script that takes list of computers in an excel sheet, looks at AD for its info, and then puts it in a excel/.txt file

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory, export-to-excel

I am pretty much a novice when it comes to PowerShell scripting, yet I have been tasked with researching and creating a script that takes an excel list full of computer names, looks for all of its info in Active Directory( user, org, location, etc.) and then spits it all out in either a .txt or excel format. I have been researching for a while and can't find a way to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated and would ease the tremendous amount of frustration I am in.

Comment: Importing and exporting Excel files can be done with the [ImportExcel module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/7.1.0). Getting AD computer objects info can be done with [Get-ADComputer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adcomputer?view=windowsserver2019-ps#:~:text=The%20Get%2DADComputer%20cmdlet%20gets,Manager%20(SAM)%20account%20name.). Then you need to read about [foreach looping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7.1).

Comment: Once you have some code you have been working on and you have some difficulty post it here and we will help you.